# A Measurable and a Non-Measurable Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Letting $A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets 
$$[3n, 3n+1), \;\;\;n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
what is an example of a measurable function $f: (\mathbb{R}, A)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},B)$, with $B$ the borelian algebra? What is an example of a non-measurable function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is an example of a measurable function. The sigma algebra consists of all possible unions of the intervals $[3n,3n+1)$ and the complement of their union  so $I_{(0,\sqrt 2)}$ is an example of  a non-measurable function.

Comment: Could you clarify which function you mean by $I_{(0,\sqrt{2})}$?

Comment: The function which is $1$ on $(0,\sqrt 2)$ and $0$ elsewhere .